# Python line continuation of function with many returns

Tags: python, pep8

I'm working on a python code which has some functions that return many values as a tuple. I'm working on updating the line continuation to bring the line lengths down to a reasonable length. Is there a correct way to format the line continuation? PEP 8 has a lot about function inputs, but nothing about outputs. I know that some of this is personal preference, but if there is any sort of accepted standard, I'd like to follow it. Option 1 looks the cleanest to my eyes, but I'm not sure if it is 'okay' to put values on the first line without vertical alignment.

Long term, I'd like to refactor so that I'm not getting so many returns from a single function, but that isn't an option at the moment. I'd like to be able to fit

Legacy

```
return_one, return_two, return_three, return_four, return_five = function_with_lots_of_returns(input)
```

Option 1

```
(return_one, return_two, 
    return_three, return_four, 
    return_five) = function_with_lots_of_returns(input)
```

Option 2

```
(
    return_one, return_two, 
    return_three, return_four, 
    return_five) = function_with_lots_of_returns(input)
```

Option 3

```
(
    return_one, return_two, 
    return_three, return_four, 
    return_five
    ) = function_with_lots_of_returns(input)
```

Comment: Do you actually use such numbered variables or rather something like `name, age, job, salary, email = ...`?

Comment: Apart from this being opinion based, some context is missing to be able to answer helpfully. It would really depend on what you are actually doing with those variables afterwards

Comment: I've heard [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is fairly popular, you could try its [playground](https://black.vercel.app) (at least to include its suggestion in your options).

Comment: They are not numbered, it is more like ````name, age, job, salary, etc...```` I don't want to post any snippets of proprietary code online, no matter how poorly it was written to begin with, haha.  
The context is a function that reads the status of a GUI. So while all of the outputs are related somewhat, they are not necessarily things that should be put together in a single construct.

Comment: Black seems to suggest Option 3, but to separate the return_yyyy's onto their own line and align the closing parenthesis with the opening parenthesis. I certainly could live with that

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, I agree that is opinion based, but sometimes something that makes sense (in my amateur opinion) has obvious pitfalls that I'm not seeing. Best practices aren't rules, but they are still best practices.

Answer (score -3):

It gets messy to individually name them all.
Cleaner to just use regular tuple assignment, not tuple unpacking:

```
retvals = function_with_lots_of_returns(input)
```

Now you can refer to your return-values as `retvals[0]`, `retvals[1]`...

Comment: @KellyBundy: it would be more constructive if you said "this is just tuple assignment, not unpacking". Yes that's correct. It beats long lines of of ad-hoc-named retvals for no reason.

Comment: I don't see one more constructive than the other, and was sure you'd understand, which you did. I'm btw not convinced `return_one` etc are their actual names, just like `function_with_lots_of_returns` presumably isn't their actual name.

Comment: @KellyBundy Just because I understood your comment, other people might well not understand and/or read it as a diss, and downvote. Anyway even if the names are `ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4, ret5` that's still longer than needs be.

Comment: I merely briefly pointed out what unpacking actually  *is* and that you weren't actually doing it. I don't see an issue.

Comment: I don't mean the length of the variables but their meaninglessness. Asked them about that now, see my comment under the question.

Comment: I had already seen your comment under the question. We agree that tuple assignment beats long lines of of ad-hoc-named retvals for no reason. I agree the OP's intent is unclear, whether the individual names are needed in their case.

Comment: Individual names are needed in this case. Code can either read input files, or use a GUI for input. The functions that have large tuple returns are for reading the files or the GUI. The ````return_one, return_two```` etc are fully separate values that really would not make sense being bundled into a single construct.